# Which drivers should I use on Lenovo z51-70

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, fglrx

Which drivers should I use on my new laptop Lenovo z51-70. It's an notebook with I3, AMD r7 m360?

When I open driver manager it says that I'm using recommended driverst. It is using the Xorg AMD drivers driver but when I open details about the sistem it says that my graphics is Intel HD. Why is my graphics detected as Intel not as AMD in details abot the sistem but in driver it says AMD?

Should I use the open ones or the fglrx?

Here are the picture of Details and Driver Manager

http://s28.postimg.org/lf794uou5/Screenshot_from_2015_10_31_18_26_51.png

http://s16.postimg.org/o8mz256h1/Screenshot_from_2015_10_31_18_42_17.png

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Well basically, it entirely depends on what you want to do(with Ubuntu). If you're just going to use it to listen to music, watch movies, etc. then the X.Org X server(open source) drivers are just fine. Ubuntu identifies the Intel HD graphics as your graphics source because Ubuntu uses it for graphics(everything you see on your screen).

In my opinion, the open source graphics drivers are just fine. However, if you're a gamer and would like to use it for gaming(e.g Steam), go [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx).

Comment: I'm not playing steam games. Only surfing on the net, playing multimedia and maybe playing free linux games like openarena.

Comment: I switched to amd drivers (fglrx) but now i have image tearing and stuttering in movies. How to solve thhis

Comment: You didn't have to change to the AMD ATI drivers, because the X. Org X server(open source drivers) are able to handle a game like OpenArena. All you have to do is go to Software and Updates, and re-enable the X.Org X Server drivers. That should get rid of the problem. You can read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56789/should-i-install-ati-propriety-video-drivers-on-ubuntu-11-04-on-my-dell-inspiron) [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7372/how-to-reduce-the-tearing-while-watching-videos) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/648492/unity-crashing-with-amd-drivers?rq=1) to help you.